# error while converting pdf to pdf/a

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to create a pdf/a file from a pdf file using itext. Everything goes fine and I get a pdf/a file. But when I check it here http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx  I get an error like

```
The width for character 1 in font 'ArialRegular' does not match.
The width for character 2 in font 'ArialRegular' does not match.
The width for character 3 in font 'ArialRegular' does not match.
```

how could I solve this error?

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file);

FontFactory.defaultEmbedding = true;
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
while (currentpagenumber < pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
    document.newPage();
    currentpagenumber++;
    finalpagenumber++;
    page = pdfAWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, currentpagenumber);
    cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    cb.beginText();
    cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 18);
    cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, finalpagenumber+"", 520, 5, 0);
    cb.endText();
    ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream(PROFILE));
```

this is the basic code. I also tried to find the font used in each page using pdfdictionary .. and tried to embeded it as base font.. but couldnot work..

Comment: Well, how do you try to use iText to create a PDF/A from a (generic) PDF? I ask because such a conversion is not a feature of iText at all. See also [here](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/PDF-Validation-error-with-PDF-A1b-complaince-tt4655986.html) on the iText mailing list.

Comment: I tried to copy the pdf file using pdfcontentbyte and write it to a pdf/a file using pdfAwriter(exactly how we add a paragraph using pdfAWriter)

Comment: I know this probably may not be the right way to do.. but I get only one error I mentioned.. I am not sure how to embed the required font

Comment: Hhmmm, directly working with the content bytes can be really complicated as you must take into account all the resources defined for the original page etc. Do you have some small sample producing a PDF showing that issue? You find many examples of iText use in the [iText in Action examples](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=1) many of them using fonts one way or another.

Comment: After you now have added the code sample: I'm afraid that code will not serve your purpose. Neither PdfAWriter.getImportedPage nor ContentByte.addTemplate does anything to ensure PDF/A-ishness. If the objects defining the page in the original PDF did not already meet the PDF/A requirements, the page in the result document won't either, and any errors in the original document are also copied. The result PDF merely will claim conformance to PDF/A (having some metadata set accordingly. Additionally using getImportedPage will remove all interactive features including stuff like digital signatures.

Comment: any Idea how exactly this could be done?..

Comment: No. I think creating a fairly generic pdf to pdf/a-XX converter means many months of work. Libraries like iText can be used to provide very low level helper methods, but checking the objects from the incoming PDF and updating them to meet PDF/A requirements still has to be implemented which is much work.

Answer (score 0):

Never used IText before, but just looking at doing a similar conversion now, and it appears to be a bug in the library and not in the way you are using it.
The best option I can give you is to report a bug at:
http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/bugs/
The IText mailing list would also be another place to try.

md_5

Comment: yes, I will try to report a bug. But if any other solution possible please post here..

Comment: Tried playing with the various embed font options? That may be a workaround, but once again it is a bug in some way or another.